# RequireJs Backbone error Collection is not a constructor when creating new Collection

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using backbone.js along with jquery and underscore.js.
the error says:
**TypeError: CollectorCollection is not a constructor

var collectors = new CollectorCollection();**

This is my index.html

```
<html><heade></head><body><script data-main="js/mainCollector" src="js/libs/require.js"></script></body>
```

mainCollector.js

```
    require.config({
    paths: {
        html5shiv: "libs/html5shiv",
        jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
        jqueryui: "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui",
        tablesorter: "libs/jquery.tablesorter.min",
        script: "script",
        underscore: "libs/underscore.min", /*"http://underscorejs.org/underscore",*/
        backbone: "libs/backbone.min", /*"http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min",*/
        utils: "utils",
        collectorModel: "models/collectorModel",
        collectorCollection: "collectorCollection",
        collectorRouter: "collectorRouter",
        edit: "views/Collector/collector_edit",
        index: "views/Collector/collector_index",
        neww: "views/Collector/collector_new",
        row: "views/Collector/collector_row",
        show: "views/Collector/collector_show"
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Jqueryui"
        },
        tablesorter: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "TableSorter"
        },
        script: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Script"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    }    
});    
require(["backbone", "underscore", "collectorCollection", "collectorRouter"],
    function (Backbone, _, CollectorCollection, CollectorRouter) {
        var Collectors = new CollectorCollection();
        var router = new CollectorRouter({collectors: collectors});
        console.log("Start App");
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

colectorCollection.js

```
 define("collection", [
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "collectorModel"
    ],  function(_, Backbone, CollectorModel) {
        console.log("Collection loaded");
        var CollectorCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            // Reference to this collection's model.
            url: "api/index.php/Collectors",
            model: CollectorModel
        });
        return CollectorCollection;
    });
```

collectorModel.js

```
define("model", ["underscore", "backbone"],  function(_, Backbone){
    console.log("model loaded");

    var CollectorModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'api/index.php/collectors',
        // the root
        paramRoot: "collector",

        // the default fields
        defaults: {
            id: null,
            name: ""
        }
    });
    return CollectorModel;
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Javascript is case sensitive
- the variable names used in the definition files are local to the definition, they won't be available when required (if you do things correctly and don't write on the global namespace),
- you [define names](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename) for your modules, which probably will lead to problems down the road

This means that `CollectorCollection` won't be available globally, and that in

```
require(["collectorCollection"], function (collectorCollection) {
}
```

your collection is actually available as `collectorCollection` : note the lowercase c.

So, your require call could be written as

```
require(["backbone", "underscore", "collectorCollection", "collectorRouter"],
    function (Backbone, _, CollectorCollection, CollectorRouter) {
        var collectors = new CollectorCollection();
        var router = new CollectorRouter({collectors: collectors});
        console.log("Start App");
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

You've got a similar problem in your collection definition :

```
define([
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "collectorModel"
    ],  function(_, Backbone, CollectorModel) {
        console.log("Collection loaded");
        var CollectorCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            // Reference to this collection's model.
            url: "api/index.php/Collectors",
            model: CollectorModel
        });
        return CollectorCollection;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i have corrected the failure of uppercase and is not the reason.

Comment: I  just noticed you define names for your your modules (your first parameter) which is probably also part of the problem. I modified the code for the collection as an example

Comment: @MustaphaKoumach Does removing the name in your module definitions help?

Comment: I've fixed the error, now I have the following error: TypeError: is not a function this._configure:<br>
var view = FcbkCollectorRowView({fcbkCollectors:     this.fcbkCollectors, fcbkCollector: fcbkCollector});
console.log("Printing row");
this.$el.find("tbody").append(view.render().el);

Comment: Chrome console gives this error:Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method '_configure'.